# How to disable a p:selectOneButton with Jquery

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I use p:selectOneButton in my page, here's a link : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneButton.xhtml

I use this component in a data table. I want to disable the selection in some case. This is my code :

```
jQuery(this).find("input[type='radio']").parent().attr('disabled', true);
```

but it doesn't work.

What is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Please post more code or details, so that we can understand what you want...

Comment: Disabling buttons clientside is dangerous. Users can easily change this

Comment: Do you want to disable all radio buttons or only a specific one and if so which one?

Comment: @Amit-InexPatel: I added more details to my question

Comment: @Kukeltje: how users can do changes ? thanks

Comment: @Denis Wessels:I want to disable all selectOneButton component buttons

Comment: with the same tool that you use when developing webpages... The browser developer tool

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code in order to disable radio buttons

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").parent().attr('disabled', true);
});`

[Here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0m7xm72/29/) that demonstrates how to disable check boxes, select elements and buttons

Comment: This works with radio buttons but not with a select on button component

Comment: I updated fiddle with examples: [1] how to disable some select options (or all select element) and [2] how to disable one button or all buttons in the fieldset.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me. p:selectOneButton is interpreted like this in html.

 `<input id="id_01" name="loption" type="radio" value="45" class="ui-helper-hidden" disabled="disabled"> `   

The solution i found is to add a div (lightbox) is the specific position.

<div class="litghbox" style="z-index:2"/>